# Need help combining gScaled if statements

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm creating a zoom function and so far it works but now I have a new problem where I'm using tons of if statements to change gScaled. I want to combine these if statements into as few as possible to make it easier to add smaller increments to the zoom later without having to write in another 100 if statements.

Code:

```
if(zoom == 1){
        glScaled( 1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    }
    if(zoom == 2){
        glScaled( 1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
    }
    if(zoom == 3){
        glScaled( 1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
    }
    if(zoom == 4){
        glScaled( 1.4, 1.4, 1.4);
    }
    if(zoom == 5){
        glScaled( 1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    }
    if(zoom == 6){
        glScaled( 1.6, 1.6, 1.6);
    }
    if(zoom == 7){
        glScaled( 1.7, 1.7, 1.7);
    }
    if(zoom == 8){
        glScaled( 1.8, 1.8, 1.8);
    }
    if(zoom == 9){
        glScaled( 1.9, 1.9, 1.9);
    }
    if(zoom == 10){
        glScaled( 2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
    }
    if(zoom == -1){
        glScaled( 0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    }
    if(zoom == -2){
        glScaled( 0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
    }
    if(zoom == -3){
        glScaled( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
    }
    if(zoom == -4){
        glScaled( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
    }
    if(zoom == -5){
        glScaled( 0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
    }
    if(zoom == -6){
        glScaled( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    }
    if(zoom == -7){
        glScaled( 0.4, 0.4, 0.4);
    }
    if(zoom == -8){
        glScaled( 0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    }
    if(zoom == -9){
        glScaled( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    }
    if(zoom == -10){
        glScaled( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    }
```

I've tried replacing the doubles with my own (I.E. gScaled( x, y, z); ) then adding to those ( x += 0.1; y += 0.1; z += 0.1; ) which does work but I can't figure out how to make it stop.

Comment: Post the replacement code also.

Comment: Have you never heard of a switch statement?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Why even bother with a switch? This is basic artithmetic.

Comment: Tried the switch also, for some reason it likes to ignore my break statements and cause an infinite loop. TY anyway

Answer (score 4):

Ehh, why not simply calculate it?

```
double const f_zoom = 1.0 + 0.1 * zoom;
glScaled(f_zoom, f_zoom, f_zoom);
```

Apart from avoiding lots of repetitive code it also prevents silly mistakes as this one you have in your code:

```
/* ... */
if(zoom == -3){
    glScaled( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
}
if(zoom == -4){
    glScaled( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
}
/* ... */
```

You see it? For both -3 and -4 the zoom factor has been coded 0.7. That's surely not what you want.